# CosmosDB Triggered Azure Function faces error when building

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to check if my azure function (CosmosDB trigger) can see the documents in my CosmosDB database, I get this error when I build the project in Visual Studio.

```html
[26-11-2018 12:08:51] Host started (33917ms)
[26-11-2018 12:08:51] Job host started
[26-11-2018 12:08:51] The following 1 functions are in error:
[26-11-2018 12:08:51] Function1: The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client: Service is currently unavailable.
[26-11-2018 12:08:51] Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client: The requested resource is no longer available at the server.

[26-11-2018 12:08:53] Retrying to start listener for function 'Function1' (Attempt 1)
[26-11-2018 12:08:53] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[26-11-2018 12:08:53] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have restarted the PC and the Visual Studio several times, and updated visual studio as well, I double checked my connection string but I still get the same error. Does anyone know what this means? and where I may have a problem?

The code I have is a standard code for Azure function:

```
    public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "cosmostest",
        collectionName: "Items",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "DBConnection",
        LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, TraceWriter log)
    {
        if (documents != null && documents.Count > 0)
        {
            log.Verbose("Documents modified " + documents.Count);
            log.Verbose("First document Id " + documents[0].Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The message _The requested resource is no longer available at the server._ makes me wonder if the database name (`cosmosdbtest`) and collection name (`Items`) are still valid? Please check you CosmosDB in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).

Comment: This was the first thing I double checked when I got the error, but unfortunately the name of my CosmosDB Database is "cosmostest" and my collectionName is "Items".

Comment: I can also see in my CosmosDB in Azure Portal, the name of the database stands as**ToDoList** and even I change the name in the code to **ToDoList**, I still get the same error.

Comment: How do I actually know that Visual Studio can find the database and the collection? 
Is there a way to find out? In my **Cloud Explorer** in Visual Studio I dont see the name of my database, is that a sign that my database cant be found?

Comment: @SSRH If you have confirmed the existence of db `cosmostest` and collection `Items` and `leases` on Azure portal Data explorer,  no firewall setting, and Cloud Explorer can't display your cosmosdb while other services are shown as expected, there could be sth wrong with your cosmosdb service. Raise a support tick for official assistance, it's the last blade on Azure portal.

Comment: I haven't created anything regarding `leases`, I just created Cosmos DB database and a collection. Is this something I should be aware of, regarding the `leases`?

Comment: @SSRH yes, the trigger requires lease collection to work with change feed. Add `CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true` in CosmosDBTrigger attribute  as the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#trigger---c-example) says .

Comment: I created a `lease` collection as well but still the same problem. 
I even used storage emulator, I upgraded everything on Visual Studio, I even used .Net Core to create it, still the same. I begin to think it may be from the computer itself since it is a company computer and might have some restriction, could that be the case?

Comment: @SSRH Great possibility there's some settings like firewall restriction since the Azure service should be reliable to some extent.